Making a two-column table with headers over each column
How could I make a table using this format? I don't care about the color.
(https://imgur.com/a/TnhQvpI)
I've used align to organize it so far, but idk how to make the table.
\begin{align*}
    &\sqrt{a^2-x^2} & x=a\sin\theta,\quad dx=a\cos\theta\;d\theta,\quad\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=a\cos\theta\\
    &\sqrt{x^2+a^2} & x=a\tan\theta,\quad dx=a\sec^2\theta\;d\theta,\quad \sqrt{x^2+a^2}=a\sec\theta\\
    &\sqrt{x^2-a^2} & x=a\sec\theta,\quad dx=a\sec\theta\tan\theta\;d\theta,\quad\sqrt{x^2-a^2}=a\tan\theta
\end{align*}


Welcome to TeX.SX! As currently formulated, this question falls in the "do-it-for-me" category which is not well received on this website. Please provide some code you have tried so far. It has to present the abstract problem you are struggling with.

Please also clarify which elements of the table shown in the screenshot are important to you. E.g., do you need the top and bottom rule to be colored in blue (or is it cyan?) and the middle rule in gray instead of black? Does the mathy material have to be rendered in \displaystyle math mode, or is "normal", i.e., \textstyle math mode ok?

Please note that no one ready to do keyin the text, so at least post your table body text along with the code what you tried so far

I only care about the style and the header. I know how to write the math text from the table. I have no idea how to make a table styled similarly to this one.

@rudytheduck Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal example of code of what you tried till now.

I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting in order to clarify the posting's main objective. Feel free to revert.

If you don't need the colored lines, a simple tabular is enough:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{CL}
  \toprule
  \makecell{\textbf{Square root form}\\\textbf{in integrand}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Trigonometric substitution}}\\
  \midrule
  \sqrt{a^2-x^2} & x=a\sin\theta,\quad dx=a\cos\theta\;d\theta,\quad\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=a\cos\theta\\
  \sqrt{x^2+a^2} & x=a\tan\theta,\quad dx=a\sec^2\theta\;d\theta,\quad \sqrt{x^2+a^2}=a\sec\theta\\
  \sqrt{x^2-a^2} & x=a\sec\theta,\quad dx=a\sec\theta\tan\theta\;d\theta,\quad\sqrt{x^2-a^2}=a\tan\theta\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


If you need the colored lines, use tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={Q[c,m]Q[l,m]},
  cell{2-Z}{1-Z}={mode=math},  
  row{1}={font=\bfseries}
  }
  \toprule[cyan]
  {Square root form\\in integrand} &
  \SetCell[c=1]{c}Trigonometric substitution\\
  \midrule
  \sqrt{a^2-x^2} & x=a\sin\theta,\quad dx=a\cos\theta\;d\theta,\quad\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=a\cos\theta\\
  \sqrt{x^2+a^2} & x=a\tan\theta,\quad dx=a\sec^2\theta\;d\theta,\quad \sqrt{x^2+a^2}=a\sec\theta\\
  \sqrt{x^2-a^2} & x=a\sec\theta,\quad dx=a\sec\theta\tan\theta\;d\theta,\quad\sqrt{x^2-a^2}=a\tan\theta\\
  \bottomrule[cyan]
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



The first table in the following screenshot closely replicates the format used in screenshot you posted. Note that I would employ an array environment instead of a tabular environment as most of the table's contents should be rendered in math mode.
I can't help but point out that this table is not well-designed from a layout point of view, as there's lots of repetitive material in columns 2, 3, and 4. The second table shown below remedies this by imposing more visual order and placing the repeated material in the header. (Aside: I'm sure you can come up with better descriptors than $x$ form and $\theta$ form.) As the modified table takes on a much more compact appearance, you'll also be less likely producing a table whose width exceeds \textwidth.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{newtx} % optional (Times Roman text and math fonts)
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} c l @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Square root form} \\
\textbf{in integrand} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\textbf{Trigonometric substitution}} \\
\midrule
\sqrt{a^2-x^2} & 
   x=a\sin\theta, \quad 
   dx=a\cos\theta\,d\theta, \quad 
   \sqrt{a^2-x^2}=a\cos\theta \\
\dots & \dots \\
\sqrt{x^2-a^2} &
   x=a\sec\theta, \quad 
   dx=a\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta, \quad
   \sqrt{x^2-a^2}=a\tan\theta \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\bigskip
\[
\begin{array}{@{} c ccc @{}}
\toprule
\mytab{Square root form\\in integrand} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textnormal{Trigonometric substitution ($x\to\theta$)}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& \textnormal{$x$ form} & dx & \textnormal{$\theta$ form} \\
\midrule
\sqrt{a^2-x^2} & 
   a\sin\theta & 
   a\cos\theta\,d\theta & 
   a\cos\theta \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\sqrt{x^2-a^2} &
   a\sec\theta & 
   a\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta &
   a\tan\theta \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}


Hope this will helps you, I've placed the Header part alone:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cl@{}}
\parbox[b]{10pc}{\centering Squar root form in integrand} & Trignometric substitution
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

